# Center <pre> Block Without Centering Text

Tags: html, formatting, pre

If I wanted to print code on an HTML page, but I want the `<pre>` block to be centered, but the actual text to be left aligned, how is this done?

Just to make it simple, what would it take to get this to center so that both lines start at the same place.?

```
<pre>int i = 0;
i = i + 80000000000;</pre>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the way you want to do it. Have a container with `display: block;` around it and `text-align: center;`. Then, add `display: inline-block;` to your `pre` tag and make it `text-align: left;`

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <pre>
int i = 0;
i = i + 80000000000;
    </pre>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   text-align: center;
 }

.container pre {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvwmnz8z/

Comment: Thanks, works well.  Just to let you know, the `<pre>` tag will print that indentation.  Best to put each line inside the pre tag on the same column as the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way if you don't want to create an extra element.

In CSS, Simply set the `pre` to use `display: flex;` and assign `center` to the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property.

```html
<pre style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">int i = 0;
i = i + 80000000000;</pre>
```